# Strictly using a taxi: LaGuardia, Newark or JFK for midtown Manhattan?

Tags: airport-transfer, new-york-city, taxis

Which New York airport would you choose for the easiest taxi transfer to midtown?

So,

1. You are using a taxi (or any similar vehicle service - limo, uber, etc.)
2. You are arriving on a domestic flight.
3. For completeness, say you are going to midtown - Times Square.
4. The taxi fare is irrelevant.

Which airport results in the quickest overall time from walking off the plane to stepping into the hotel?

So again, you can choose which of the three airports you'll arrive at. Which one is quickest and easiest for a taxi to town?

Comment: When do you plan to arrive? Rushour traffic severely impacts the answer/options

Comment: EWR is probably the simplest - you can take a simple train right to Penn Station - but the fastest is likely to fly into LGA.  However, I've not tested it.  Incidentally, the answer will be the same from major Canadian airports too as passengers will be pre-cleared and arrive as domestic passengers.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie the question assumes taxi, car service, etc., so the existence of train service to Penn Station is not particularly helpful.  (Such service also exists from JFK, and is somewhat less expensive if I recall correctly.)

Comment: Walking in Manhattan will be the same -- a few meters from the curb to the door.  Walking at the airport depends on the terminal.

Comment: hi @SebastianJ. , thanks, surely, an answer would mention the difference.  Timing flexible - looking for a canonical answer to "taxi from the airports"! (Since oddly the question, as such, hasn't been on here!)

Comment: hi @JimMacKenzie, the question is about **taxis only**, thanks. That's an interesting point about Canada arrivals, I did not know that.

Comment: I had and Answer that address taxi vs limo vs Uber but OP didn't like one extraneous detail.  TL/DR: Uber, right now, the airport does't really matter.

Comment: @Fattie Notwithstanding traffic, LGA is closest, therefore if taking a taxi, LGA will be the fastest if other forms of transport aren't permitted.  It's a pretty long taxi ride to midtown from both JFK and EWR.

Comment: https://www.newyorkhelicopter.com/airport-transfers/

Comment: hey @StephanBranczyk, I love taking a helicopter, but it is impractical (and way expensive) if you have too many people, luggage etc. (And the Manhattan helipads are in totally crap locations, so you have to schlepp in a taxi anyway.)  The QA is about, uh, wheeled vehicle services, per point 1 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simple matters of geography, barring a major accident on the GCP or other adjacent roads, La Guardia will offer the quickest trip by car into any part of Manhattan among the three main commercial airports. (Teterboro probably beats it for uptown destinations, but TEB has no commercial service).

Terminal A (a.k.a. the Marine Air Terminal) is particularly convenient, as it is on the far western edge of the airport, and has a simple layout, and is smaller, making it easier to navigate once off the plane, faster to get a cab at the taxi stand, and quicker to get onto the BQE, thence to the bridge (or, I suppose, the tunnel, but my cabbies always seem to prefer the bridge). In fact, back when the terminal was used by the shuttles, Pan Am and then Delta used its convenience as a selling point.

- *It looks like as of writing JetBlue and Alaska use Terminal A. [Reference](http://laguardiaairport.com/lgaonthemove/)*

Yes, LGA is totally chaotic with the [massive construction](http://laguardiaairport.com/redevelopment/) going on. I think, however, that this only makes JFK and EWR more competitive, not clear winners in either case. LGA is simply geographically closest to Manhattan, and thus offers the least uncertainty. With EWR you have the risk of tunnel traffic, which can add an hour if you arrive at the wrong time of day. JFK is on the far side of Queens and almost necessitates time on [the Van Wyck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8AS_tisvQI).

Comment: This is a great answer, @choster, thanks.  I was thinking, to make the answer even more canonical, could someone outline *which airlines/flights?* particularly use Terminal A ?  What's the deal on that?  Great answer thanks.

Comment: I can't see the Seinfeld reference!  (Comedians in cars going to the airport?)

Comment: @fattie I didn't include the airlines as there is likely to be some more shuffling as construction progresses, but for right now they are jetBlue and Alaska; Delta vacated it completely in last year's big swap. There are a couple of references to the Van Wyck Expressway on *Seinfeld*, but the video clip I linked is probably the most famous one.

Comment: Ah - construction.  Sounds gnarly.  So JetBlue and Alaska - huh no big major airlines eh?  Bummer.  Reference - ah, I didn't notice your video link, good one  :)